# Jquery Tablesorter lost StickyHeaders widget

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560664/jquery-tablesorter-loss-of-functionality-after-ajax-call) question I have similar problem. I have a table with a `stickyHeaders` widget (it allows to fix the table headers while scrolling). Also I have a checkboxes in some of table cells. On `$('checkbox').change(function(){});` I send some data to `request.php` and reload my table by `$('#tableid').append(data);` The problem is that my headers hide when I click on any checkbox and then appear again if I scroll mouse wheel or resize the table (so do some 'refresh').

I tried:

```
$('#sortTable').trigger('update', [true]);
$('#sortTable').trigger('refreshWidgets', true, false);
```

No result.
How can I fix this?

[image: It is good]
[image: Where is my StickyHeaders??]

Comment: Try `$(window).scroll()` and if that doesn't work, please share a demo of this issue - modify [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/856bzzeL/) as needed.

Comment: thanks, I found the solution, something like you adviced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So solved it like this

```
$('#sortTable').resize();
```